# Aggregate and select only top records with $last

Tags: mongodb

I have following collection in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "assetId" : "...",
    "date" : ISODate("..."),
    ...
}
```

I need to do quite simple thing - find latest record for each device/asset. I have following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$match" : { "assetId" : { "$in" : [ up_to_80_ids ]} } }, 
    { "$group" :{ "_id" : "$assetId" , "date" : { "$last" : "$date"}}}
])
```

Whole table is around 20Gb. When I am trying to do this query it takes around 8 seconds which does not make any sense, as far as I specified that only $last record should be selected. Both assetId and date are indexed. If I add **{ $sort : { date : 1 } }** before group it does not change anything.

Basically, result of my query should NOT depend on data size. The only thing I need is a top record for each device/asset. If I do instead 80 separate queries it takes me few milliseconds.

Is there any way to make MongoDB to do NOT go through whole table? It looks like database does not reduce but processes everything?! Well, I understand that there should be some good reason for this behaviour but I cannot find anything in documentation or on the forums.

**UPDATE:**

Eventually found right syntax of explain query for 2.4.6:

```
db.runCommand( { aggregate: "collection", pipeline : [...] , explain : true })
```

Result:

```
{
        "serverPipeline" : [
                {
                        "query" : {
                                "assetId" : {
                                        "$in" : [
                                                "52744d5722f8cb9b4f94d321",
                                                "52791fe322f8014b320dae41",
                                                "52740f5222f8cb9b4f94d306",
... must remove some because of SO limitations
                                                "52744d1722f8cb9b4f94d31d",
                                                "52744b1d22f8cb9b4f94d308",
                                                "52744ccd22f8cb9b4f94d319"
                                        ]
                                }
                        },
                        "projection" : {
                                "assetId" : 1,
                                "date" : 1,
                                "_id" : 0
                        },
                        "cursor" : {
                                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor assetId_1 multi",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "n" : 960881,
                                "nscannedObjects" : 960881,
                                "nscanned" : 960894,
                                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 960881,
                                "nscannedAllPlans" : 960894,
                                "scanAndOrder" : false,
                                "indexOnly" : false,
                                "nYields" : 9,
                                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                                "millis" : 6264,
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "assetId" : [
                                                [
                                                        "52740baa22f8cb9b4f94d2e8",
                                                        "52740baa22f8cb9b4f94d2e8"
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        "52740bed22f8cb9b4f94d2e9",
                                                        "52740bed22f8cb9b4f94d2e9"
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        "52740c3222f8cb9b4f94d2ea",
                                                        "52740c3222f8cb9b4f94d2ea"
                                                ],


                                                ....


                                                [
                                                        "5297770a22f82f9bdafce322",
                                                        "5297770a22f82f9bdafce322"
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        "529df5f622f82f9bdafce429",
                                                        "529df5f622f82f9bdafce429"
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        "529f6a6722f89deaabbf9881",
                                                        "529f6a6722f89deaabbf9881"
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        "52a6e35122f89ce6e2cf4267",
                                                        "52a6e35122f89ce6e2cf4267"
                                                ]
                                        ]
                                },
                                "allPlans" : [
                                        {
                                                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor assetId_1 multi",
                                                "n" : 960881,
                                                "nscannedObjects" : 960881,
                                                "nscanned" : 960894,
                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                        "assetId" : [
                                                                [
                                                                        "52740baa22f8cb9b4f94d2e8",
                                                                        "52740baa22f8cb9b4f94d2e8"
                                                                ],
                                                                [
                                                                        "52740bed22f8cb9b4f94d2e9",
                                                                        "52740bed22f8cb9b4f94d2e9"
                                                                ],
                                                                [
                                                                        "52740c3222f8cb9b4f94d2ea",
                                                                        "52740c3222f8cb9b4f94d2ea"
                                                                ],

                                                                .......

                                                                [
                                                                        "529df5f622f82f9bdafce429",
                                                                        "529df5f622f82f9bdafce429"
                                                                ],
                                                                [
                                                                        "529f6a6722f89deaabbf9881",
                                                                        "529f6a6722f89deaabbf9881"
                                                                ],
                                                                [
                                                                        "52a6e35122f89ce6e2cf4267",
                                                                        "52a6e35122f89ce6e2cf4267"
                                                                ]
                                                        ]
                                                }
                                        }
                                ],
                                "oldPlan" : {
                                        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor assetId_1 multi",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "assetId" : [
                                                        [
                                                                "52740baa22f8cb9b4f94d2e8",
                                                                "52740baa22f8cb9b4f94d2e8"
                                                        ],
                                                        [
                                                                "52740bed22f8cb9b4f94d2e9",
                                                                "52740bed22f8cb9b4f94d2e9"
                                                        ],
                                                        [
                                                                "52740c3222f8cb9b4f94d2ea",
                                                                "52740c3222f8cb9b4f94d2ea"
                                                        ],


                                                        ........


                                                        [
                                                                "529df5f622f82f9bdafce429",
                                                                "529df5f622f82f9bdafce429"
                                                        ],
                                                        [
                                                                "529f6a6722f89deaabbf9881",
                                                                "529f6a6722f89deaabbf9881"
                                                        ],
                                                        [
                                                                "52a6e35122f89ce6e2cf4267",
                                                                "52a6e35122f89ce6e2cf4267"
                                                        ]
                                                ]
                                        }
                                },
                                "server" : "351bcc56-1a25-61b7-a435-c14e06887015.local:27017"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "$group" : {
                                "_id" : "$assetId",
                                "date" : {
                                        "$last" : "$date"
                                }
                        }
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: What I think happened here, is that mongodb used an index on deviceId. It can only use one index per query, so it couldn't use an index on date. Can you post the output of explain?

Comment: updated question with explain() output.. If MongoDB is really cannot use more than one index in aggregation query then it explains performance problem..

Comment: What are the indexes for this collection? You mention that both "asset_id" and "date" are indexed - but they need to be in the same index for the most benefit. MongoDB 2.4 will only use a single index per query unless the query contains `$or` clauses. Also, although you are only asking for the `$last` date value, the aggregation query will still have to iterate all matching values in order to find the last per group. The *result* of your current query doesn't depend on data size, but the *execution* time of your query will.

Comment: I would try: adding an index on `{assetId:1, date:-1}`; add a `{$sort: { 'date': -1}}` operation after the `$match`; take the `$first` match per group instead of the `$last`.

Comment: thanks a lot and @Stennie, your comments were very helpful in order to find out what's the problem. I think that should be mentioned in aggregate documentation, big read notification! I just found similar example in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/. I actually have few different queries to that collection and each time assetId and date are used together. So this is more design mistake. I am going to create compound index and remove assetId and date indexes.

Comment: Hi @Stennie. Nothing changed after we added compound index. Index is picked up correctly, but aggregation framework still scanning all records. Actually there is no difference between how $last and $first behave comparing to $max, $avg, etc. This is a bit confusing. For the moment I cannot use aggregation framework and I am very disappointed with how it works. I am wondering if this is described somewhere in documentation or should I open a ticket?

Comment: New index: { assetId : 1, date: -1 }

Comment: Query: db.runCommand( { aggregate: "waypoint", pipeline : [ { "$match" : { "assetId" : { "$in" : [ "52791f3222f8014b320dae39", "52791c3e22f8014b320dae1c"]} }} , { "$sort" : { "assetId" : 1 , "date" : -1}} , { "$group" :{ "_id" : "$assetId" , "date" : { "$first" : "$date"}}}] , explain : true })     takes >50s

Comment: 50s?  how about the second time you run it?  does it take less time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `explain` output indicates there are 960,881 items matching the assetIds in your `$match` stage. MongoDB finds all of them using the index on `assetId`, and streams them all through the `$group` stage. This is expensive. At the moment MongoDB does not make very many whole-pipeline optimizations to the aggregation pipeline, so what you write is what you get, pretty much.

MongoDB could optimize this pipeline by sorting by assetId ascending and date descending, then applying the optimization suggested in [SERVER-9507](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9507) but this is not yet implemented.

For the moment, your best course of action is to do this for each assetId:

```
db.collection.find({assetId: THE_ID}).sort({date: -1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: Yes, we currently issue single command per asset. Thanks for pointing to ticket.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but if you read this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last) on monngodb site.

it has NOTE that ***Only use $last when the $group follows an $sort operation. Otherwise, the result of this operation is unpredictable.***

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my program. I have tried mongoDB MapReduce, aggregation framework and other but finally I've stopped on scanning collection using indexes and forming result on client. But now collections is too big to do that so I think I will use many small queries as you mentioned above in your question. It is not so beautifull but it will be the fastest solution IMHO.

Only the first query in your pipeline use index. The second query in pipeline accept output of the first query and it is big and not indexed. But as mentioned in [Pipeline Operators and Indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes) your query can use compound index so it is not so clear.

I have an idea: you can try to use many `$or` operators instead one `$in` operator like this
`{ "$match": { "$or": [{"assetId": <id1>}, {"assetId": <id2>...}] } }`. As I know `$or` operator can be executed in parallel and each query can use index. So it would be interesting to test this solution.

p.s. I really will be happy if solution for this problem will be found.

Comment: $or definitively doesn't work. In case with $in nscanned=673967, for $or nscanned=14458579, e.g., whole db. And takes almost minute.

Comment: @ruruskyi, strange.. I've tried it on my collection about 20 GB and when used $in and $or nscanned was equal. But first execution was long may be because index was not in memory. Other calls were approximately equal. P.S. I am increasingly convinced that aggregation framework is only suitable for offline operations...